# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on Lenovo Ideapad Z570 with an integrated GPU (Intel with nvidia Cuda) does not wake up after suspend

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, suspend, gpu, nvidia-optimus

I too have the same issue. I am using a old laptop with follwing configuration
Lenovo Ideapad z570 with intel core i3 2nd gen + 12gb DDR3 RAM
This machine has an integrated GPU (Intel with nvidia Cuda) on its motherboard. But I disabled nvidia from BIOS and am only using it in UMA mode - meaning my graphics now only runs on Intel GPU.
I was using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS for last almost 8 years. Now, I recently fresh installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on this machine.

This is the currently running kernel of my machine:

```
hk@hk-Ideapad-Z570:~$ uname -mrs
Linux 5.15.0-56-generic x86_64
```

Everything is running great and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS too is really great and I like it so much. THis ofcourse is very well and efficiently utilizing my old laptop's resources.
Right from day one of installing this version on this laptop, there is this waking up problem everytime my laptop is suspended. It doesn't wake up with any of the key presses - not even with the press of power button. Its not just black screen after it wakes up from suspend! It does not wake up at all as the connected mouse too doesn't switch on. The entire laptop just freezes and not even numLock and capsLock keys work.

Various debates on this and other forums suggested to upgrade your kernel version which worked for them on Lenovo laptops with intel + nvidia GPUs. I too did install couple of latest kernel versions and tried but this issue is still present. Currently I am on the super latest 6.0.9 kernel and this issue is still present :-(

```
hk@hk-Ideapad-Z570:~$ uname -mrs
Linux 6.0.9-060009-generic x86_64
```

Here is the full listing of lshw from my listing. I will be happy to give any further outputs of any required commands which you think can really help in solving this really frustrating issue.

```
   hk@hk-Ideapad-Z570:~$ sudo lshw
    [sudo] password for hk: 
    hk-ideapad-z570             
        description: Notebook
        product: HuronRiver Platform (System SKUNumber)
        vendor: LENOVO
        version: Ideapad Z570
        serial: WB01628180WB0103160B
        width: 64 bits
        capabilities: smbios-2.6 dmi-2.6 smp vsyscall32
        configuration: administrator_password=unknown boot=normal chassis=notebook family=HuronRiver System frontpanel_password=unknown keyboard_password=unknown power-on_password=unknown sku=System SKUNumber uuid=e042f35f-4c51-e011-8f74-8ac5dc0379c5
      *-core
           description: Motherboard
           product: Emerald Lake
           vendor: LENOVO
           physical id: 0
           version: FAB1
           serial: WB01628180
           slot: Part Component
         *-firmware
              description: BIOS
              vendor: LENOVO
              physical id: 0
              version: 45CN28WW
              date: 02/22/2011
              size: 128KiB
              capacity: 2560KiB
              capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video pc98 acpi usb biosbootspecification netboot
         *-cpu
              description: CPU
              product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz
              vendor: Intel Corp.
              physical id: 30
              bus info: cpu@0
              version: 6.42.7
              serial: Not Supported by CPU
              slot: CPU
              size: 1690MHz
              capacity: 2100MHz
              width: 64 bits
              clock: 100MHz
              capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave avx lahf_lm epb pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
              configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 microcode=47 threads=4
            *-cache:0
                 description: L1 cache
                 physical id: 31
                 slot: L1-Cache
                 size: 64KiB
                 capacity: 64KiB
                 capabilities: synchronous internal write-through data
                 configuration: level=1
            *-cache:1
                 description: L2 cache
                 physical id: 32
                 slot: L2-Cache
                 size: 256KiB
                 capacity: 256KiB
                 capabilities: synchronous internal write-through data
                 configuration: level=2
            *-cache:2
                 description: L3 cache
                 physical id: 33
                 slot: L3-Cache
                 size: 3MiB
                 capacity: 3MiB
                 capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
                 configuration: level=3
         *-memory
              description: System Memory
              physical id: 34
              slot: System board or motherboard
              size: 12GiB
            *-bank:0
                 description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
                 product: KN2M64-MIN
                 vendor: Kingston
                 physical id: 0
                 serial: E1355603
                 slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
                 size: 8GiB
                 width: 64 bits
                 clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
            *-bank:1
                 description: DIMM [empty]
                 physical id: 1
                 slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
            *-bank:2
                 description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
                 product: HMT351S6CFR8C-H9
                 vendor: Hynix/Hyundai
                 physical id: 2
                 serial: 4E85D5D5
                 slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
                 size: 4GiB
                 width: 64 bits
                 clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
            *-bank:3
                 description: DIMM [empty]
                 physical id: 3
                 slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
         *-pci
              description: Host bridge
              product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
              vendor: Intel Corporation
              physical id: 100
              bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
              version: 09
              width: 32 bits
              clock: 33MHz
            *-display
                 description: VGA compatible controller
                 product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
                 vendor: Intel Corporation
                 physical id: 2
                 bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
                 logical name: /dev/fb0
                 version: 09
                 width: 64 bits
                 clock: 33MHz
                 capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
                 configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1366,768
                 resources: irq:27 memory:d0000000-d03fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
            *-communication
                 description: Communication controller
                 product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
                 vendor: Intel Corporation
                 physical id: 16
                 bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
                 version: 04
                 width: 64 bits
                 clock: 33MHz
                 capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
                 configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
                 resources: irq:26 memory:d0605000-d060500f
            *-usb:0
                 description: USB controller
                 product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
                 vendor: Intel Corporation
                 physical id: 1a
                 bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
                 version: 05
                 width: 32 bits
                 clock: 33MHz
                 capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
                 configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
                 resources: irq:16 memory:d060a000-d060a3ff
               *-usbhost
                    product: EHCI Host Controller
                    vendor: Linux 6.0.9-060009-generic ehci_hcd
                    physical id: 1
                    bus info: usb@1
                    logical name: usb1
                    version: 6.00
                    capabilities: usb-2.00
                    configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
                  *-usb
                       description: USB hub
                       product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                       vendor: Intel Corp.
                       physical id: 1
                       bus info: usb@1:1
                       version: 0.00
                       capabilities: usb-2.00
                       configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
                     *-usb:0
                          description: Mouse
                          product: 2.4G Mouse
                          vendor: SHARKOON Technologies GmbH
                          physical id: 2
                          bus info: usb@1:1.2
                          logical name: input6
                          logical name: /dev/input/event5
                          logical name: input7
                          logical name: /dev/input/event6
                          logical name: /dev/input/mouse1
                          version: 2.00
                          capabilities: usb-1.10 usb
                          configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
                     *-usb:1
                          description: USB hub
                          product: 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
                          vendor: Generic
                          physical id: 3
                          bus info: usb@1:1.3
                          version: 1.33
                          capabilities: usb-2.10
                          configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
                        *-usb
                             description: Generic USB device
                             product: USB 10/100/1000 LAN
                             vendor: Realtek
                             physical id: 4
                             bus info: usb@1:1.3.4
                             version: 30.00
                             serial: 000001000000
                             capabilities: usb-2.10
                             configuration: driver=r8152 maxpower=180mA speed=480Mbit/s
                     *-usb:2
                          description: Video
                          product: Lenovo easy camera: USB2.0-Came
                          vendor: 5618006211B3778S
                          physical id: 5
                          bus info: usb@1:1.5
                          logical name: input12
                          logical name: /dev/input/event9
                          version: 25.14
                          serial: 200901010001
                          capabilities: usb-2.00 usb
                          configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
            *-multimedia
                 description: Audio device
                 product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
                 vendor: Intel Corporation
                 physical id: 1b
                 bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
                 logical name: card0
                 logical name: /dev/snd/controlC0
                 logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D0
                 logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D3
                 logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c
                 logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
                 logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
                 version: 05
                 width: 64 bits
                 clock: 33MHz
                 capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                 configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                 resources: irq:28 memory:d0600000-d0603fff
               *-input:0
                    product: HDA Intel PCH Mic
                    physical id: 0
                    logical name: input10
                    logical name: /dev/input/event10
               *-input:1
                    product: HDA Intel PCH Headphone
                    physical id: 1
                    logical name: input11
                    logical name: /dev/input/event11
               *-input:2
                    product: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3
                    physical id: 2
                    logical name: input13
                    logical name: /dev/input/event12
            *-pci:0
                 description: PCI bridge
                 product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
                 vendor: Intel Corporation
                 physical id: 1c
                 bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
                 version: b5
                 width: 32 bits
                 clock: 33MHz
                 capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode cap_list
                 configuration: driver=pcieport
                 resources: irq:16
            *-pci:1
                 description: PCI bridge
                 product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2
                 vendor: Intel Corporation
                 physical id: 1c.1
                 bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
                 version: b5
                 width: 32 bits
                 clock: 33MHz
                 capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                 configuration: driver=pcieport
                 resources: irq:17 memory:d0500000-d05fffff
               *-network
                    description: Wireless interface
                    product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
                    vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                    physical id: 0
                    bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                    logical name: wlp2s0
                    version: 01
                    serial: 68:a3:c4:54:27:f0
                    width: 64 bits
                    clock: 33MHz
                    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=6.0.9-060009-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.109 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                    resources: irq:17 memory:d0500000-d050ffff
            *-pci:2
                 description: PCI bridge
                 product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4
                 vendor: Intel Corporation
                 physical id: 1c.3
                 bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
                 version: b5
                 width: 32 bits
                 clock: 33MHz
                 capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                 configuration: driver=pcieport
                 resources: irq:19 ioport:2000(size=4096) ioport:d0400000(size=1048576)
               *-network
                    description: Ethernet interface
                    product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
                    vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                    physical id: 0
                    bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                    logical name: enp3s0
                    version: 05
                    serial: f0:de:f1:49:e0:6e
                    capacity: 100Mbit/s
                    width: 64 bits
                    clock: 33MHz
                    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
                    configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.0.9-060009-generic firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
                    resources: irq:19 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d0404000-d0404fff memory:d0400000-d0403fff
            *-usb:1
                 description: USB controller
                 product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
                 vendor: Intel Corporation
                 physical id: 1d
                 bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
                 version: 05
                 width: 32 bits
                 clock: 33MHz
                 capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
                 configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
                 resources: irq:23 memory:d0609000-d06093ff
               *-usbhost
                    product: EHCI Host Controller
                    vendor: Linux 6.0.9-060009-generic ehci_hcd
                    physical id: 1
                    bus info: usb@2
                    logical name: usb2
                    version: 6.00
                    capabilities: usb-2.00
                    configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
                  *-usb
                       description: USB hub
                       product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                       vendor: Intel Corp.
                       physical id: 1
                       bus info: usb@2:1
                       version: 0.00
                       capabilities: usb-2.00
                       configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
                     *-usb
                          description: MMC Host
                          product: USB2.0-CRW
                          vendor: Generic
                          physical id: 6
                          bus info: usb@2:1.6
                          logical name: mmc0
                          version: 39.60
                          serial: 20100201396000000
                          capabilities: usb-2.00
                          configuration: driver=rtsx_usb maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
            *-isa
                 description: ISA bridge
                 product: HM65 Express Chipset LPC Controller
                 vendor: Intel Corporation
                 physical id: 1f
                 bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
                 version: 05
                 width: 32 bits
                 clock: 33MHz
                 capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
                 configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
                 resources: irq:0
               *-pnp00:00
                    product: PnP device PNP0c02
                    physical id: 0
                    capabilities: pnp
                    configuration: driver=system
               *-pnp00:01
                    product: PnP device PNP0b00
                    physical id: 1
                    capabilities: pnp
                    configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
               *-pnp00:02
                    product: PnP device INT3f0d
                    physical id: 2
                    capabilities: pnp
                    configuration: driver=system
               *-pnp00:03
                    product: PnP device PNP0303
                    physical id: 3
                    capabilities: pnp
                    configuration: driver=i8042 kbd
               *-pnp00:04
                    product: PnP device SYN0326
                    physical id: 4
                    capabilities: pnp
                    configuration: driver=i8042 aux
               *-pnp00:05
                    product: PnP device PNP0c02
                    physical id: 5
                    capabilities: pnp
                    configuration: driver=system
               *-pnp00:06
                    product: PnP device PNP0c01
                    physical id: 6
                    capabilities: pnp
                    configuration: driver=system
               *-input
                    product: Ideapad extra buttons
                    physical id: 7
                    logical name: input8
                    logical name: /dev/input/event7
                    capabilities: platform
            *-sata
                 description: SATA controller
                 product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Mobile SATA AHCI Controller
                 vendor: Intel Corporation
                 physical id: 1f.2
                 bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
                 logical name: scsi0
                 logical name: scsi4
                 version: 05
                 width: 32 bits
                 clock: 66MHz
                 capabilities: sata msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list emulated
                 configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
                 resources: irq:24 ioport:3088(size=8) ioport:3094(size=4) ioport:3080(size=8) ioport:3090(size=4) ioport:3060(size=32) memory:d0608000-d06087ff
               *-disk
                    description: ATA Disk
                    product: TOSHIBA MK6465GS
                    vendor: Toshiba
                    physical id: 0
                    bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
                    logical name: /dev/sda
                    version: 4E
                    serial: 11MDC3TKT
                    size: 596GiB (640GB)
                    capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                    configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=4febed93-93ea-46ca-9af6-786b17e27c84 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
                  *-volume:0
                       description: Windows FAT volume
                       vendor: mkfs.fat
                       physical id: 1
                       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                       logical name: /dev/sda1
                       logical name: /boot/efi
                       version: FAT32
                       serial: 5858-ccc5
                       size: 510MiB
                       capacity: 511MiB
                       capabilities: boot fat initialized
                       configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro name=EFI System Partition state=mounted
                  *-volume:1
                       description: EXT4 volume
                       vendor: Linux
                       physical id: 2
                       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                       logical name: /dev/sda2
                       logical name: /
                       logical name: /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                       version: 1.0
                       serial: a6422ed7-fdd3-4a67-a03f-97f2ff0b210b
                       size: 595GiB
                       capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                       configuration: created=2022-12-23 18:25:58 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2022-12-27 12:17:17 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=ro,noexec,noatime,errors=remount-ro mounted=2022-12-27 12:17:43 state=mounted
               *-cdrom
                    description: DVD-RAM writer
                    product: DVDRAM GT33N
                    vendor: HL-DT-ST
                    physical id: 1
                    bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
                    logical name: /dev/cdrom
                    logical name: /dev/sr0
                    version: LE01
                    capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
                    configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
            *-serial
                 description: SMBus
                 product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
                 vendor: Intel Corporation
                 physical id: 1f.3
                 bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
                 version: 05
                 width: 64 bits
                 clock: 33MHz
                 configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
                 resources: irq:18 memory:d0604000-d06040ff ioport:efa0(size=32)
      *-battery
           product: Smart Battery
           vendor: Intel Corp.
           physical id: 1
           version: 2008
           serial: 1.0
           slot: Rear
      *-power UNCLAIMED
           description: TBD by ODM
           product: TBD by ODM
           vendor: TBD by ODM
           physical id: 2
           version: 1.0
           serial: TBD by ODM
           capacity: 32768mWh
      *-input:0
           product: Lid Switch
           physical id: 3
           logical name: input0
           logical name: /dev/input/event0
           capabilities: platform
      *-input:1
           product: Sleep Button
           physical id: 4
           logical name: input1
           logical name: /dev/input/event1
           capabilities: platform
      *-input:2
           product: Power Button
           physical id: 5
           logical name: input2
           logical name: /dev/input/event2
           capabilities: platform
      *-input:3
           product: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
           physical id: 6
           logical name: input3
           logical name: /dev/input/event3
           logical name: input3::capslock
           logical name: input3::numlock
           logical name: input3::scrolllock
           capabilities: i8042
      *-input:4
           product: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
           physical id: 7
           logical name: input5
           logical name: /dev/input/event4
           logical name: /dev/input/mouse0
           capabilities: i8042
      *-input:5
           product: Video Bus
           physical id: 8
           logical name: input9
           logical name: /dev/input/event8
           capabilities: platform
      *-network
           description: Ethernet interface
           physical id: 9
           bus info: usb@1:1.3.4
           logical name: enx7cc2c61cadbd
           serial: 7c:c2:c6:1c:ad:bd
           size: 1Gbit/s
           capacity: 1Gbit/s
           capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
           configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.12.13 duplex=full firmware=rtl8153a-3 v2 02/07/20 ip=192.168.0.125 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
    hk@hk-Ideapad-Z570:~$
```

I am so very frustrated with this 'laptop not waking up from suspend' issue and wasted a good full 3 days in trying to get this work by various (almost all) ways. Now, I am here with a tired brain and heart asking you guys out there for help. How can I make my laptop resume cleanly from suspend with this configuration? Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my LeNovo IdeaPad Flex 5.
Many users has that kind of problems, especially AMD GPU laptops, for many years without a solution yet.

Try this (Gnome Tweaks):

```
General > Disable "Suspend when laptop lid is closed".
```

After that, close the lid or lock the screen and check if worked.
Worked for me, even after disable and enabling back how it was, restarted my laptop several times without problems until now.

Comment: hey   , this is not with AMD GPU. As i clearly stated at the beginning of my question its with nvidia GPUs. It doesn't wake up with any of the key presses - not even with the press of power button. Its not just black screen after it wakes up from suspend! It does not wake up at all as the connected mouse too doesn't switch on. The entire laptop just freezes and not even numLock and capsLock keys work.